# Spring Data MongoDB Date field is not working on Query or Aggregation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, date

Spring-Boot Repository class:

```
@Query("{ 'dob' : { $gt: ?0  } }")
    List<Brokers> findByDobLessThan(Date from);
```

Generated log:

```
find using query: { "dob" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : 1585918200956}}} fields: Document{{}} for class: 
class com.kallam.middleware.model.broker.Brokers in collection: brokers
```

This is the data in mongo databse which is in different format.
MongoDb data:

```
{
"dob" : ISODate("1986-02-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "dow" : ISODate("2011-02-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "creditLimit" : 0,
    "adjustBills" : "NONE",
    "contactRelation" : "NILL",
    "occupation" : "TYRE RETRADING",
    "age" : 0,
    "caste" : "Nill",
    "gender" : "MALE",
    "createdDt" : ISODate("2020-04-03T11:54:14.900Z"),
    "updatedDt" : ISODate("2020-04-03T11:54:14.901Z"),
    "ownrent" : "TRUE",
    "simbrand" : "AIRTELL"
}
```

My findings:

I found that Java is converting date to long (time) and passing to database so database can't recognize because it is in different format.

I am using Java 1.8, Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE, spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb.

Comment: What is the date input you are passing to your `findByDobLessThan(Date from)` query?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.